# The Instagram bot works but doesn't post the video

Tags: python, video, instagram

I'm trying to make an instagram bot that posts videos. I use instabot. The function "upload_photo ()" works and publishes the photo but "upload_video" does not give an error in the code but does not publish the video

**Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from instabot import Bot
import os
import glob
import datetime
cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*cookie.json")
os.remove(cookie_del[0])
bot = Bot()
monthList = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jule', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
dt = datetime.datetime.today()
day = dt.day
month = dt.month



bot.login(username = "*************",
          password = "**************")

bot.upload_video("/home/pi/fileToRun/video/OriginalVideo{0}-{1}.mp4".format(day,month),
                 caption ="Today {0} of {1}".format(day,monthList[month]))
```

**Output**

> The code "works" but doesn't post the video

````
2021-05-25 10:26:18,273 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2021-05-25 10:26:18,276 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-05-25 10:26:21,382 - INFO - Logged-in successfully as '***********'!
2021-05-25 10:26:21,383 - INFO - LOGIN FLOW! Just logged-in: True
2021-05-25 10:26:32,570 - INFO - Started uploading '/home/pi/fileToRun/video/OriginalVideo25-5.mp4'
Analizing `/home/pi/fileToRun/video/OriginalVideo25-5.mp4`
FOUND w:200, h:200, rotation=0, ratio=1.0
Square video
2021-05-25 10:26:52,980 - INFO - Video '/home/pi/fileToRun/video/OriginalVideo25-5.mp4' uploaded
2021-05-25 10:26:52,982 - INFO - Total requests: 43
```
````